# Cross fading animation (key frame image duration)

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

Here I have some example  css code of a cross fading image animation that transitions between two images, however I'm struggling to figure out how to change the length of the image duration to around 10 seconds rather than an instant transition. The animation length is fine I set that to 3 seconds. I just want the image to stay for 10 seconds before transitioning to the other image. From my understanding it seems you have to change the code which has opacity and the percentages but I can't figure out the syntax for this css. Any help would be appreciated. Here is a  of what I currently have. Also here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/21Lex38c/) if it helps.

Here is my CSS:

```
/*INDEX PAGE CSS*/
 #index_banner {
    height:360px;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#index_banner img {
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-animation: cf4FadeInOut 3s;
    animation: cf4FadeInOut 3s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes cf4FadeInOut {
    0% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@keyframes cf4FadeInOut {
    0% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
#index_banner img:nth-child(odd) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
    animation-delay: 4s;
}
#welcome_text {
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2em;
}
#trailer_title {
    text-align: center;
}
#trailer_video {
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom:20px;
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="index_banner">
                                         <img class="bottom" src="images/SPAWN IMAGE.png" alt="INDEX BANNER">
                                         <img class="top" src="images/SURVIVAL IMAGE - GAMEMODES.png" alt="INDEX BANNER 2">
                                     </div>
```

Comment: @jbutler483 he has already tried that, it will work fine first time. But once animation has started, it will no longer maintain the gap of 10 seconds.

Comment: Yeah, this is really confusing me. I've tried many different things.

Comment: @Grant412 Try to increase the duration of Animation. For Example make it of 13s and for 10s do nothing. Do your thing in last 3 seconds. Hope you are getting the point.

Comment: I've tried and it doesn't seem to change anything, I probably haven't fully understood what you mean, example code would help a lot. If you can be bothered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated Version
Check this output result https://jsfiddle.net/5ac3cLtv/5/

I did following things to get the desired result.

1) Set `position:absolute;` for images.

2) Increased Animation time to **15s**.

3) Included `animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;`, it will bring smoothness to the start and end of our animation.

4) Gave `animation-delay:8s` to **#index_banner img:nth-child(odd)**.

5) Changed keyframes as given below:

```
@keyframes cf4FadeInOut {

   0% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    30% {
        opacity:0; 
    }
    40%{
        opacity:1; 
    }
    75%{
        opacity:1; 
    }
    85%{
        opacity:1; 
    }

    100% {
        opacity:0;
    }

}
```

**Keyframes Explanation**

All what keyframes are doing is, fading in the image after 4.5 seconds (i.e 30% of 15 seconds). Image is kept there for about 4-5 seconds and start fading it out slowly.

*Why INDEX BANNER 1 is appearing in the start?*

Because I have put animation-delay for it. So it will start fading out after 8 seconds. As our Animation starts from opacity:0 .

Comment: The timing works, but I don't use Firefox only chrome. I just copied this code into the web kit and the normal key frame changed the animation duration to 10s and the image duration was ok however the animation sort of faded into the other image that instantly switched back to the first one. Here is a fiddle of what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/5ac3cLtv/, also why have my other centred elements been forced left?

Comment: Actually you are using `position:absolute` which is merging both images. Use `position:relative` instead. Why do both of the images animate at the same time? Because you haven't mentioned `animation-delay` on any of them yet. I have given the delay of 2s in this jsfiddle and also fixed the positioning problem. Check it out https://jsfiddle.net/5ac3cLtv/4/  NOTE: I have also fixed the cross-browser issue, now it will work on both, Chrome and Mozilla.

Comment: Afraid is not what I want still. I want the images on top of each other, changing the position to relative displays two images not one over the other also now this happens: http://gyazo.com/969a094386a285dedaec23e0238e0f55

Comment: I basically want it exactly like demo 3 of this guide: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/

Comment: I have updated my main answer which is given above, according to your need. Check it out.

Comment: Brilliant! it works, and I certainly have more of an understanding of the idea of key frames. Without a doubt you are one of the, most helpful people I've ever met on this site. I sincerely thank you for your patience.